# TimeLimitError when removing all occurrences of a string from another string

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I'm doing an exercise in which I have to remove all occurrences of a string from another string and, although it works, it seems that the program is iterating and infinite amount of times and I can't fix it. I know there is a string.replace() function but I wanted to try to solve the problem without using the fuction.
This is the code:

'''
def remove_all(substr,theStr):

```
index = theStr.find(substr)
if index > 0:
    newstr = ""
    while index > 0:
        sizsub = len(substr)
        newstr = theStr[:index] + theStr[(index + len(substr)):]
        index = newstr.find(substr)
    return newstr
else:
    return theStr
```

remove_all("an", "banana")

'''

the error message: "TimeLimitError: Program exceeded run time limit. on line 9"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check if index is greater than -1, not 0, because 0 is the first index.
Inside `while` you are cuting the initial `theStr` every time ,which causes `newstr` to be same thing and stuck in loop.

You can solve this by giving initail value equal to `theStr` for `newstr` and cut the `newstr` instead of `theStr` inside loop.

```py
def x(substr, theStr):
    index = theStr.find(substr)
    if index > -1:
        newstr = theStr
        while index> -1: 
            sizsub = len(substr)
            newstr = newstr[:index] + newstr[index + sizsub:]
            index = newstr.find(substr)
        return newstr
    else:
        return theStr

print(x('an', 'banana'))
# prints => ba
```